# After migrating to latest version of xCode my app does not build, fails due to watchkit

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, cfbundleidentifier

I was on xCode 6.x.  My app also had a WatchApp in it.  All of which were running fine.

I upgraded to  8.1.

When I tried to build the .ipa got loads of errors all of which seem to relate to the WatchKitApp.

[image: List of Errors when tried to build the ipa]

Answer (score 0):

Look in your main app target.

Select Build Phases tab.

Select Copy Bundle Resources

Find your WatchKitApp bundle 'Appname WatchKit App.app' and remove it by selecting it and then clicking on the '-' sign at the bottom of the list of items under Copy Bundle Resources.

Rebuild the .ipa and all of these errors will no longer occur.

Problem solved.